# AngularJS call controller function in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, i'm doing some things mixing AngularJS and Canvas but I'm kind of noob in both.

In a controller, I have a function like this:

```
app.controller('headerController',function(){
 this.status = header; //This is declared down of this
 //Other properties of the controller

 this.init = function(){
 var thumbImg = document.createElement('img');
 thumbImg.src = this.status.drawUrl;
 this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.status.name);
 this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
 this.ctx.save();
 document.getElementById('texto').textContent = 'sdaas'; //This is just to see fast if it has worked
 }
 });
```

And in html, I have this:

```
<div ng-controller="headerController as header">
    <canvas ng-attr-id="{{header.status.name}}" ng-click="header.init()" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
</div>
```

You see that with the ng-click I call the controller function, and that works fine. The problem is that I want to call the function without having to click it,  but I don't understand angular that well to know how to do it. I've seen some things about $scope but that seems like something I'll have to study from scratch, and I can do everything I need right now just with this doubt solved (I don't have that much time to learn all about Angular right now..). It would be something like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="headerController as header">
        <canvas ng-attr-id="{{header.status.name}}" ng-click="header.init()" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
<script>
header.init();
</script>
    </div>
```

So, any idea to do it and keep it simple and clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-init instead of ng-click and then it will intinal it without the click event.

```
<canvas ng-attr-id="{{header.status.name}}" ng-init="header.init()" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Actually not. It doesn't work, it seems to call the function before canvas is loaded, so whent it gets to line "this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")" it says "cannot read property "getContext" from null. It only happens with ng-init, with ng-click it still works fine. So, seems like I need a way to trigger it when the html/canvas fully loads? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @the_scion, if you are using angular 1.6 you should consider using a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) which has `$onInit` that can be used instead of manually calling `init()`.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I will make sure to look into it once I make everything work!